# asp.net calling function with returned value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

im calling a function that returns a string from javascript, but responseText is Undefined.
the function is in the home controller.

```
$.post("/Home/GetUserFullName").responseText
```

I understand it is because the call is asynchronous?
How can i call the function from home controller and retrieve the returned value synchronously?

Comment: Is it JQuery? It doesn't matter what server technology is. Did you look at JQuery tutorial? Your question is super confusing...

Comment: Hi Felix, why is it confusing? 
I need to assign a value to a variable in javascript with the returned value from the function in home controller(GetUserFullName).
when using 
 $.post("/Home/GetUserFullName").responseText
the function in the controller is working but responseText is undefined